# footer at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, new-operator

I've looked everywhere and I've tried almost everything and I can't seem to understand why my work is messing up. I even asked my ict teacher for help but I didn't want to tell him that it didn't show up since he spent ages on it.

Anyways, uh quite frustrated since everything is going wrong. I just want my footer to be at the bottom of the page and for me to write on the page without it going into the header.

coding for website: https://gist.github.com/JazmineCz/12884de1cf76ce72f3265b83c13aab76

Comment: here's the coding omg sorry

https://gist.github.com/JazmineCz/12884de1cf76ce72f3265b83c13aab76

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<footer>` just act as a `<div>` and don't have some special property to get at the bottom of the page.

*Your page don't have that much content so that the footer get to the bottom, What I mean is footer is at correct place at the end of page as your page is ending there*

One thing you can do is fill up the page.
another was to move it to bottom are using css.
2 things you can do either *give the article section a `height:100vh` this will make the Article section a vertical page long*, or *make the footer's `postion:fixed` and then set `bottom:0` this will fix the position of footer and *it will be not move even you scroll*

Answer (score 0):

You need to give height to your section. For example;

```
section {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Your footer is in the bottom actually. Since you don't have enough content between, it doesn't have a place at the bottom.